# How do you remove the default outline around input elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like know if is possible disable "focus" which is set by default browser in input elements?

**Update**

When an input element is in focus, the browser adds a border (typically blue) around it. This is breaking my layout. So I wonder if you can disable it.

Comment: Please explain _exactly_ what you mean by `disable "focus"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove the default focus on submit button in HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335877/how-to-remove-the-default-focus-on-submit-button-in-html-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `outline:0;` on those elements.

Comment: Not supported in IE 6/7, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your CSS:

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

[how to remove the default focus on submit button in HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335877/how-to-remove-the-default-focus-on-submit-button-in-html-form)