# how to prevent an enter key on textbox from redirecting to another page on asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, html

I have a problem whenever I press enter when I am inputing something on a textbox.
I am aware that there are panels that allow you to run the exact function of a button, however, this time when I press enter on a textbox, it usually sends me to a different page on my solution.

Sincerely, I have no idea why that happens, even the page that the system sends me to varies, and sometimes I can't tell why that happens.

Is there a way or something I can do so that whenever you press enter on a textbox, it does nothing (I suppose that not even postback)??

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335877/how-to-remove-the-default-focus-on-submit-button-in-html-form

Comment: I don't think you're randomly redirected to a different page. Hitting enter probably causes a submit of the page (perhaps a button on the page)

Comment: Are you wanting `validation`? Look into `RequiredFieldValidators`, `RegularExpressionValidators`, `CompareValidators`, etc.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAlAgendaLugar" runat="server" Width="130px">
</asp:TextBox>

Example of textbox

If by any chance, I press enter when it's focused on the textbox..
if there are no validators (or all validators will not be triggered), it triggers the function of a button on the current page (I don't know how it determines which button will be triggered, but it does not seem to be random)

Comment: As explained in rene's link, hitting enter is just supposed to submit the page, it's also what most people will expect to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Catch the keypress event and stop the page from executing the request:
This is using jquery:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode && keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%=id_of_textbox.ClientID %>").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $("#<%=id_of_search_button.ClientID %>").click();
      return false;
    }
});
```